# Updated: Generating Envelope with eNotary Signature, Seal, DateSigned TABS thru eSign api

Tags: docusignapi

In our organization dmz web application, On behalf of Signer(our client) we generate envelopes and send it to notary. And we are trying to utilize the Signature, Seal, DateSigned TABS in eNotary (InPersonSigner Receipient) envelope thru eSign API in sandbox environment. But docusignapi is not allowing us to create Signature, Seal, DateSigned TABS, but it allows only Notarize TAB.

How we can utilize the Signature, Seal, DateSigned TABS for Notary thru eSign API?

Updated Code throws attached error "Notary_Signing_Host_Tabs_Not_Allowed":

```
            string signerEmail = "signer@domain.com";
            string signerName = "Signer";

            string notaryEmail = "notary@domain.com";
            string notaryName = "Notary";

            // Step 1. Create the envelope definition
            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition();

            envelope.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document";

            byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Execute_and_Notarize.pdf");
            Document doc1 = new Document();
            String doc1b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64;
            doc1.Name = "Notarize1_1page"; // can be different from actual file name
            doc1.FileExtension = "pdf";
            doc1.DocumentId = "1";

            // The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
            envelope.Documents = new List<Document> { doc1 };

            Notarize notarize1 = new Notarize
            {
                AnchorString = "/notary1/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "10",
                Required = "true"
            };
            SignHere notarizesignhere1 = new SignHere
            {
                AnchorString = "/notarysigner1/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "10"
            };
            SignHere notarizesignhere2 = new SignHere
            {
                AnchorString = "/notarysignerseal1/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "10",
                IsSealSignTab = "true"
            };
            DateSigned notarizedatesigned1 = new DateSigned()
            {
                AnchorString = "/notarysigner1ds/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "10"
            };

            Tabs notaryTabs = new Tabs
            {
                NotarizeTabs = new List<Notarize> { notarize1 },
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { notarizesignhere1, notarizesignhere2 },
                DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned> { notarizedatesigned1 }
            };

            NotaryHost notaryHost = new NotaryHost()
            {
                Email = notaryEmail,
                Name = notaryName,
                DeliveryMethod = "email",
                RecipientId = "2",
                Tabs = notaryTabs
            };

            // Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
            // We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
            //
            // The DocuSign platform seaches throughout your envelope's
            // documents for matching anchor strings.
            SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
            {
                AnchorString = "/signer1/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "10"
            };
            DateSigned dateSigned1 = new DateSigned()
            {
                AnchorString = "/signer1ds/",
                AnchorUnits = "pixels",
                AnchorXOffset = "10",
                AnchorYOffset = "10"
            };
            // Tabs are set per recipient / signer
            Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
            {
                SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 },
                DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned> { dateSigned1 }
            };

            // Create a signer recipient to sign the document, identified by name and email
            // We set the clientUserId to enable embedded signing for the recipient
            // We're setting the parameters via the object creation
            InPersonSigner inPersonSigner1 = new InPersonSigner()
            {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name = signerName,
                RecipientId = "1",
                InPersonSigningType = "notary",
                Tabs = signer1Tabs
            };

            inPersonSigner1.NotaryHost = notaryHost;

            // Add the recipient to the envelope object
            Recipients recipients = new Recipients
            {
                InPersonSigners = new List<InPersonSigner> { inPersonSigner1 },
            };

            envelope.Recipients = recipients;
```

[Image Attachment: errorCode - notary_signing_host_tabs_not_allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uybA.png)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one line at least:

```
inPersonSigner1.NotaryHost = notaryHost;
```

Here is a C# snippet taken from [my blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-using-enotary-programmatically) on the subject:

```
// To complete this code snippet, you will need an Envelope and a Document object
var notarizeTab = new Notarize
{
    XPosition = "100", 
    YPosition = "100"
};
var signHereTab = new SignHere
{
    XPosition = "200",
    YPosition = "200"
};
var notarizeTabs = new List<Notarize>();
notarizeTabs.Add(notarizeTab);
var signHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
signHereTabs.Add(signHereTab);
var notaryHost = new NotaryHost
{
    Name = "Nadia Notary",
    Email = "nadianotary@domain.com",
    DeliveryMethod = "email",
    RecipientId = "2",
    Tabs = new Tabs { NotarizeTabs = notarizeTabs }
};
// InPersonSigner is used here even if the signer doesn't sign in person
var inPersonSigner = new InPersonSigner
{
    NotaryHost = notaryHost,
    Name = "Eddie End User", 
    Email = "endusersigner@domain.com", 
    RecipientId = "1",
    InPersonSigningType = "notary",
    Tabs = new Tabs { SignHereTabs = signHereTabs }
};
var inPersonSigners = new List<InPersonSigner>();
inPersonSigners.Add(inPersonSigner);
var recipients = new Recipients{ InPersonSigners = inPersonSigners };
```

You can add whatever tabs you need, but the important thing is to understand that the notary is a different recipient and they have their own separate tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
And "NotaryHost.Tabs = notaryTabs;" line define separate tabs for the notary host  and "inPersonSigner1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;" line defines seperate tabs for the signer. In the below code snippet notaryhost is assigned to the inpersonsigner1.NotaryHost
"InPersonSigner inPersonSigner1 = new InPersonSigner()
            {
                Email = signerEmail,
                Name = signerName,
                RecipientId = "1",
                InPersonSigningType = "notary",
                NotaryHost = NotaryHost
            };"

Comment: I know it's weird, but that's how the eNotary feature was designed.

Comment: updated code gives "errorCode":"Notary_Signing_Host_Tabs_Not_Allowed", "message": "Only notarize tabs allowed for the notary signing host". And just want to make sure, "Does the eNotary feature will allow only Notarize tab in NotaryHost, not Signature, Seal, DateSigned tabs?"

Comment: oh, yes, a notaryHost is a special recipient and is limited to this type of tab.

Comment: you could workaround this limitation by adding the notary again as a regular signer.